# How to login to a site using OAuth, python?

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

So I have a script which needs access to features of a website which requires login via OAuth.

I already have an OAuth client secrets file from the dev console- right now my script can successfully retrieve a list of a user's youtube videos- this is what I have now

```
__author__ = 'anish'

import httplib2
import sys

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

# Most of the code is sourced from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = "Missing client secrets"

def get_credentials(args):
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE)
    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

    return credentials

def videos(youtube, uid):
    initial = youtube.playlistItems().list(part="snippet", maxResults=50,
                                           playlistId="UUy2Lh8b-y0r-35LlcjOPPzw").execute()
    yield initial
    while "nextPageToken" in initial:
        initial = youtube.playlistItems().list(part="snippet", maxResults=50,
                                           playlistId="UUy2Lh8b-y0r-35LlcjOPPzw",
                                           pageToken=initial["nextPageToken"]).execute()
        yield initial

if __name__ == "__main__":

    video_list = []

    http = get_credentials(argparser.parse_args()).authorize(httplib2.Http())

    rq = http.request("http://github.com", method="GET")
    print(rq[1])

    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
        http=http)

    info = youtube.channels().list(part="contentDetails", forUsername="IndianaRobotics").execute()
    uploads_id = info["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]

    for v in videos(youtube, uploads_id):
        for item in v["items"]:
            video_list.append([item["snippet"]["title"], item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]])

    for v_info in video_list:
        print(v_info)
```

So my access token to Google API's works. However, when I do things like

```
print(http.request("http://github.com", method="GET")
```

I get the login page as a response, even though I use OAuth to sign into github and the credentials I have are from my account.

Is there any way to use the `http` object I have to login to a site like github? I need to to it without any sort of API from the site itself because the website I'd like to interact with, [thebluealliance](http://thebluealliance.com) doesn't have an API for OAuth

Comment: While you could use `oauth2client` to get credentials for sites that implement OAuth2 (including github), it wouldn't work for a website that doesn't have an API or implement OAuth2.